# Is Flink's WindowOperator deterministic when allowedLateness is specified?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to understand how can Flink's streaming WindowOperator be deterministic when allowedLateness is specified.

Say, we are doing event time based (not processing time) processing. The initial watermarks are generated at the source. And then every operator computes its watermark as well. In case when there are [parallel streams](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/concepts/time/#watermarks-in-parallel-streams), the watermark is the minimum across all inputs.

Now let's say we are processing parallel streams and one of the inputs is paused (for whatever reason). In this case, the watermark would not advance and there would be no late events.
But if this input was not paused, the watermark would be advancing and there would be some late events.

So how is event processing deterministic in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Once you put a bounds on max lateness, your workflow is no longer deterministic. From Flink's [Timely Stream Processing](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/concepts/time/):

> In a perfect world, event time processing would yield completely consistent and deterministic results, regardless of when events arrive, or their ordering. However, unless the events are known to arrive in-order (by timestamp), event time processing incurs some latency while waiting for out-of-order events. As it is only possible to wait for a finite period of time, this places a limit on how deterministic event time applications can be.